# How do I connect to Facebook from an ASP.NET webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, facebook

I want to create a webservice that allows user to connect to Facebook. In my webservice, there is a method named "connect" which requires 2 parameters: the username and password (of the Facebook account).

I have to use this username and password to connect to Facebook from the webservice. After that, I want to allow the user to post on their walls...Is is it possible to connect to Facebook using a webservice?

I tried a lot, and I can login to Facebook account, but I can't get the sessionkey and userid.

How can I integrate Facebook in an ASP.NET webservice?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: People will post answers to your question (or questions for you, if they have any) right here on Stack Overflow. That's encouraged over sending private emails, because the solutions are available on the Internet to anyone else who might have the same problem. (If you find it more convenient to be notified via email when there are responses to your question, there are options for that in your user profile.)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Connect Authentication for ASP.NET is a component that allows ASP.NET web developers to identify and validate users accessing their website or web services using Facebook Connect.

It is written in C#, targeted at .NET 2.0.

http://fbconnectauth.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this Tutorial to authenticate the users in ASP.NET application

http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-retrieve-user-data-from-facebook-connect-in-aspnet/